# Display data if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have array checkbox (category) and I want to display list of checkbox size if one of them is being checked. I have already made the JavaScript but it didn't work out. Here's my code:

View

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<div class="mb-0 ml-2">
 <label class="mb-0">
  <input class="category mb-0" id="category" name="category[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $category->id }}" onChange="this.form.submit()" 
  @if (in_array($category->id, $checkedCat)) checked @endif>
  {{ $category->name }}
 </label>
</div>
@endforeach

<div id="size" class="sizefilter">
//List of size checkbox
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#category").on('change', function() {
 if($('input[name="category[]"]:checked'))
 {
    $(".sizefilter").show();
 } else
 {
    $(".sizefilter").hide();
 }
});
```

Comment: this will always return a non false value: `if($('input[name="category[]"]:checked'))`

Comment: in your loop `id` needs to be unique as well. currently the `id` would be same for all inputs.

Comment: 2 changes should make it works.  First: ```$(".category").on```. Second: ```if($('input[name="category[]"]:checked').length)```

Comment: hi ikhvjs, ive tried but it didnt change anything